# Inserting Data from Grabbing URL Parameter - PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have, for example, this URL with spesific paramater in the end:

```
http://example.com/index.php?id_user=84759832475
```

The value `[id_user=**84759832475**]` is created by myself and I have declared it inside my script.

```
$txtemail = strip_tags(isset($_POST['txtemail'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['txtemail']) : '';
$txtemail=strip_tags($txtemail);
$txtname = strip_tags(isset($_POST['txtname'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['txtname']) : '';
$txtname =strip_tags($txtname);
$id_user="84759832475";

$stmt="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE emailz=:txtemail AND namez=:txtnamez"; 
$pgdata = $myDb->prepare ($stmt);
//bind semua variabel login dalam parameter
$pgdata->bindParam(':txtname', $txtname, PDO::PARAM_STR,31);
$pgdata->bindParam(':txtemail', $txtemail, PDO::PARAM_STR,31);
//eksekusi statemen prepare tadi
$pgdata->execute();
//cek & lihat hasil
//$cekdata = $pgdata->fetchColumn();
if(!$pgdata->rowCount()> 0){
    $pgdata = $myDb->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (namez,emailz,userid) VALUES (:txtname,:txtemail,?????)');
    $pgdata->execute(array(':namez'=>$txtname, ':emailz'=>$txtemail, ':userid'=>$id_user));
```

In this case, the question mark **??????** makes me confused of what to write. 
I'm sorry if my English is too bad to explain this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another named placeholder inside that other prepared statement, just like the others:

```
$txtemail = isset($_POST['txtemail']) ? strip_tags($_POST['txtemail']) : '';
$txtname = isset($_POST['txtname']) ? strip_tags($_POST['txtname']) : '';
$id_user = "84759832475";

$stmt = 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM table_name WHERE emailz = :txtemail AND namez = :txtnamez'; 
$pgdata = $myDb->prepare($stmt);

$pgdata->bindParam(':txtnamez', $txtname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pgdata->bindParam(':txtemail', $txtemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pgdata->execute();

$result = $pgdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result['total'] > 0){

    $pgdata = $myDb->prepare('
      INSERT INTO table_name (namez,emailz,userid) 
      VALUES (:txtname, :txtemail, :userid)
    ');
    // just add another named placeholer :userid

    $pgdata->execute(array(':txtname'=> $txtname, ':txtemail'=> $txtemail, ':userid' => $id_user));
}
```

Comment: It works!, but that's not real ID(number). It works fine in number. It could be mix (number and letters). I try to modify and add new Input text with "Hidden" type and set the script <?php echo strip_tags($_post['id_user']); ?>. Then everything's done. I do appreciate

Comment: @HermanNz oh okay, that `$id_user` was just an example and the real value should be inside the form, well that make sense, im glad this helped

Comment: Sure, @Ghost, must be inside the form ... that's why I like this sweet and incredible forum .. :D